# python wav processing, nframe not equal to actual number of frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio

I'm trying to use webrtcvad to detect speech in wav file, to do so I must provide 30ms of 16bit pcm at 32Khz.
what I'm trying to do is to cut my wav in packet of 30ms but take this file for example (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91396766/recording000001.wav) :

```
audio software : 
5,568 seconds, 16 bit, mono, 320000Hz
```

-

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html
w.getnframes() = 178176
w.getframerate() = 32000
w.getnchannels() = 1 = mono
w.getsampwidth() = 2 byte = 16 bits
len(w.readframes(w.getnframes())) = 356352, shouldn't it be 178176?
len(w.readframes(0)) = 1
```

why is len(w.readframes(w.getnframes())) = 356352, it should be 178176 because

1/32000 = 0.00003125 seconds
and 0.00003125*175176 = 5.568 secs

Thanks

## Edit

test script :

```
import wave

infile = 'recording000001.wav'
w = wave.open(infile, 'rb')

data = w.readframes(w.getnframes())
frequency = w.getframerate()
number_of_channels = w.getnchannels()
sample_width_in_bytes = w.getsampwidth()

print "{} is sampled at {}Hz, it has {} channel(s) and a sample width of {} bytes".format(infile, frequency, number_of_channels, sample_width_in_bytes) 
print "it contains {} data".format(len(data))
print "for {} frames".format(w.getnframes())
print "one data length is {}".format(len(data[0]))

w.close()
```

output :

```
recording000001.wav is sampled at 32000Hz, it has 1 channel(s) and a sample width of 2 bytes
it contains 356352 data
for 178176 frames
one data length is 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

> w.rewind()

I tried

> len(w.readframes(0))
>
> 0

Which is different from your results, where you got 1.

Interestingly however,

> len(w.readframes(1))
>
> 2

But this makes sense, in a convoluted fashion, since there are indeed 2 bytes. (16bit audio frames imply that there are 2 bytes per frame. Since you are calling len on a binary object, I think it therefore makes sense that it would return the number of actual bytes.)

If you want to work on your audio data, perhaps you should investigate a library like numpy to do further analysis or processing of your audio.

> import numpy as np
>
> c = np.frombuffer(w.readframes(w.getnframes()), dtype="int16")
>
> c.shape
>
> (178175,)
>
> c[0] = 100
>
> c[1] = 122
>
> c[100] = -132

This is the raw waveform data. It is on the range of (-2^15, 2^15) or, -32768 to 32,768. Since the first portion of your audio file is quiet at the beginning, small values in the first few hundred frames makes good sense.

Comment: try this : 

frames = w.readframes(w.getnframes())
print len(frames[0])
>>> 1

Comment: frames[356352] is out of range, but frames[356351] is a valid index [BUT, not a valid measure of your audio]. This is because you are getting the uint8 values of the bytes. It takes a small extra step to ensure your uint16 numbers (2-bytes) are handled correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant int8 and int16 types, respectively. Not uint8 and uint16.

Comment: To directly reply to your comment, len(frames[0]) throws an error because calling len() on an integer is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, a lot make sense now, however len(frame[0]) does not raise an error for me, it returns 1

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Python is usually much better about shielding you from these kind of low level implementation details,